# How to debug c# in vs code on windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I installed on windows 7 visual studio code editor for developing asp.net mvc application. I know now support debug c# only for linux and Mac.

How to debug c# in vs code on windows?

P.S. Yes, i know about visual studio community. But i want try working in vs code.

Comment: Google->How to debug in C#

Comment: @mybirthname I think that's going to give a lot of answers for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code which is a completely different program.

Comment: [Debugging in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: See that link above. Look for Mono debugging.

Comment: there only debug Node.js Applications foer windows, but i ask how debug c#

Comment: _Due to this focus many standard C# project types are not recognized by VS Code. An example of a non-supported project type is an ASP.NET MVC Application. In these cases if you simply want to have a lightweight tool to edit a file - VS Code has you covered. If you want the best possible experience for those projects and development on Windows in general, we recommend you use Visual Studio Community._ -- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

Comment: i undestand this, but i want only know how can i debug c# without visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, VS Code only supports debugging for Node on Windows

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

However, watch for future updates as well as the extension marketplace